# How do I turn off bracket match highlight? (Sublime Text 3/4)

Tags: sublimetext3

I am trying to turn off bracket match highlight (the one underlined with yellow). How do I do that? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setting that you want is `match_brackets`, which controls the feature as a whole; setting it to `false` will stop all highlighting of this type.

There is a selection of settings that provide control over this (shown with their default values below) that you can also use to dial in the effect you want, if you want it in some cases but not others.

Note that some of the below settings may be ST4 only; your question is tagged as ST3 but it's common to be using ST4 without realizing; you can tell for sure by checking the default preferences (left hand pane of `Preferences > Settings`) to see which settings you have available to you.

```json
    // Set to false to disable underlining the brackets surrounding the caret
    "match_brackets": true,

    // Set to false if you'd rather only highlight the brackets when the caret is
    // next to one
    "match_brackets_content": true,

    // Set to false to not highlight square brackets. This only takes effect if
    // match_brackets is true
    "match_brackets_square": true,

    // Set to false to not highlight curly brackets. This only takes effect if
    // match_brackets is true
    "match_brackets_braces": true,

    // Set to false to not highlight angle brackets. This only takes effect if
    // match_brackets is true
    "match_brackets_angle": false,
```